# Module '"@angular/fire/firestore"' has no exported member 'AngularFirestoreModule'

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore' ;  // => Error

Module '"@angular/fire/firestore"' has no exported member 'AngularFirestoreModule'

**package.json**

> "@angular/fire": "^7.0.4",

Comment: import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';

Comment: I have already answered that question you can see in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69203459/angularfiremodule-has-not-been-provided-using-v7-0-1-and-new-method-of-initializ/69332387#69332387

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and in the GitHub repo (https://github.com/angular/angularfire) is explained how to adjust the code for the new version

```
import { Firestore, collectionData, collection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
...
item$: Observable<Item[]>;
constructor(firestore: Firestore) {
    const collection = collection(firestore, 'items');
    this.item$ = collectionData(collection);
  }
```

You also have to change the way you initialize the app in the app.module.ts

```
import { provideFirebaseApp, getApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp({ ... })),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
  ],
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular has changed its angularfire syntax right away. Check their github repo; thus just google Angularfire github and you will see their new codes. I myself am disappointed Angular has to change their firebase codes...\

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).